# JMeter override timers / reduce timer for certain step in larger scope

Tags: jmeter

I am running a JMeter scenario which has a certain think time applied for the entire scenario.

During one small loop in this scenario, I wish to decrease the think time between each sampler. E.g., if the default scenario think time, for all samplers, is 500ms, I wish to make this one small loop have a think time of only 100ms.

It does not seem like this is possible, but I also don't see any other questions asking this. Does anyone know of a workaround to accomplish what I am trying for?

This line in the JMeter docs suggests that this is not possible:

> Note that timers are processed before each sampler in the scope in which they are found; if there are several timers in the same scope, all the timers will be processed before each sampler.

https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers

Comment: "scenario which has a certain think time applied for the entire scenario" -- how exactly it's implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

1. Declare a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) to hold the default think time somewhere in [User Defined Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables)

   [image]
2. In all [Constant Timers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) (or in the one if it's applied to all the Samplers) set it to use the JMeter Variable from the step 1:

   [image]
3. Before entering your "small loop" add a [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) to the last Sampler and put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   vars.put('think-time', '100')
   ```

   [image]

   In the above code `vars` stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, see [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) article for more information if needed.
4. Before exiting the "small-loop" do the reverse thing and restore the original value of the think time

   [image]